# Location Manager in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

this is my location manager code

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 200;
mapView.showsUserLocation=true;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

this is another function also used to startupdatelocation

```
- (void)startLocationManager:(NSTimer *)timer
{  
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

and here is the

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Testing");

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(startLocationManager:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:NO];
}
```

this is working fine but the app doesn't run in background. if i remove the `NStimer` and doesn't stop location manager, app runs perfectly fine in the background. i want the location manager to run after every 1 minute to update the coordinates. the app should also run in background.

Comment: No-no-no-no, not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) (especially section "Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks"). In particular it states that

> There are several ways to track the user’s location in the background,
>   most of which do not actually require your app to run continuously in
>   the background:
>
> - The significant-change location service (Recommended)
> - Foreground-only location services
> - Background location services

You should not use the location manager like you are in the background.

> An app that provides continuous location updates to the user (even
>   when in the background) can enable background location services by
>   including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in its
>   Info.plist file. The inclusion of this value in the UIBackgroundModes
>   key does not preclude the system from suspending the app, but it does
>   tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new
>   location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run
>   in the background to process location updates whenever they occur.

There is a tutorial with a bit more info on how to do this [here](http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/).